# need id's of objects from Django query where customer id's are distinct - DB mysql

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Models -

```
class CfgXmppSessions(models.Model):

     objid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

     customer_objid = models.ForeignKey('CstContact', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,db_constraint=False, db_column='customer_objid', db_index=False)

     character_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
     character_channel_type = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

     character_objid = models.ForeignKey('PerfCharacter', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,db_constraint=False, db_column='character_objid', db_index=False)
```

I want all objid where customers are unique

Comment: Please share the relevant models and explain *what* you want, not *how* you want to do this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want all objid where customer_objid are unique Please check model for your refrence

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
def GetObjectID():
    customerIDs = list(CfgXmppSessions.objects.values('customer_objid').distinct())
    objectIDs = []
    for id in customerIDs:
        objectIDs.append(CfgXmppSessions.objects.filter(customer_objid = f"{id}").values("customer_objid"))
    return objectIds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objids = [session.get('max_objid') for session in list(CfgXmppSessions
                                                       .objects.filter(character_objid=9100)
                                                       .values('customer_objid')
                                                       .annotate(max_objid=Max('objid')))]
```

This works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).